# How to submit a form in a shadow box?

Tags: javascript

I'm using shadow box to submit a form, and since I'm new to JavaScript it's little difficult for me. I have three pages, a parent window, a child window(shadow box content) with the form and an update page to show the results. When I submit the form data in the child window, the form doesn't close and I am unable to retrieve the vales in my update page.

Can you please suggest me a tutorial or example that will help me to get a better idea of how to do this?

This is my code so far

// parent window(index.php)

```
<html>
   <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shadowbox/shadowbox.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="shadowbox/shadowbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    Shadowbox.init();
    </script>
   </head>
  <body>
```

Example shaodow box

```
<script language="javascript">
    $('#mylink').click(function(){
        Shadowbox.open({
            content:    'mybox.php',
            player:     'iframe',
            height:     550,
            width:      800,
            options: {
                onClose: 
                    function() {
                     top.location       = "update.php";                 

                    }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

//mybox.php

```
<form name="theform" action="update.php"  method="POST">
<input type="text" name="nametxt" id= "nametxt"><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

//update.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['nametxt']))
echo $_POST['nametxt'];
?>
```

please consider, this is just an example.when the form is submitted data needs to be shown in update php.
can any one help, Thanks in advance

Comment: You should post the code you have so far, so we can help you develop it.

Comment: Thanks Josh, i posted my code, I would be glad if you can help me with this, Since im new to web development i don't have good understanding about this,

Answer (score 0):

Check out this simple example of submitting a form on NetTuts: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

First, since the form you are submitting is in an iframe, by default, the result of the POST will be also. You can use target="_top" on the iframe to redirect this to the top level,sothe page is submitted to update.php and the output replaces the whole page. Check the documentation for Shadowbox to see how to set this parameter.

Another option would be to store the output in the session and send it back in the second GET request that results from your top.location = "update.php".

This is easiest if you name the resultts page something else, but it depends on your application.